# How to stream upload CSV data to Google Cloud Storage (Python)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, sqlalchemy, stream, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to upload data from a query to a CSV file in Google Cloud Storage. To prevent the system from running out of RAM ( the result of the query is huge ), I'm streaming the query results, and need to stream those to a CSV file in Google Cloud Storage.

The [documentation on streaming to Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/streaming#storage-stream-upload-object-python) shows an example with a file_obj, which is then uploaded, but I don't see how I can stream the data dynamically using this methodology.

E.g. what I'm looking for is something like this:

```
blob.start_stream_upload()
for(record in db_query_stream):
    record = ",".join(record) # turn db query record into CSV data line
    blob.write_to_stream(record)
blob.finish_stream_upload()
```

Where `write_to_stream` would add `record` to the upload stream to `blob` ( the CSV file / blob object in the Google Cloud Storage ). For reference, the `db_query_stream` is an iterable object that dynamically streams results according to [SQLAlchemy's stream_results](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#streaming-with-a-dynamically-growing-buffer-using-stream-results) option.

If anyone knows and could share how to do this, would much appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Use [google.cloud.storage.fileio.BlobWriter](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest/google.cloud.storage.fileio.BlobWriter):

```py
from google.cloud import Client
from google.cloud.storage.fileio import BlobWriter
storage_client = Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket('my_bucket')
blob = bucket.blob('my_object')

writer = BlobWriter(blob)
for(record in db_query_stream):
    record = ",".join(record) # turn db query record into CSV data line
    writer.write(record)
writer.close()
```